# Manual Windows 10 rollback from windows.old?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I'm looking for the Windows 10 equivalent of this process described in this support page:

http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/971760

http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/971760/how-to-restore-a-windows-7-based-computer-to-a-previous-windows-instal

Or does basically this same procedure also work to try to go back to a previous Windows 10 version?

Would the "bootsect" command be different (i.e., is the flag /nt99 or some other number) or does it need to be run at all when the prior version is also Windows 10?

---

*Details: Why I'm looking for this, rather than the standard Rollback procedure:*

*My Windows 10 laptop recently forced a version upgrade (from a prior Windows 10 version to the latest), and it failed spectacularly for unknown reasons.  Now the machine won't even boot.  I researched and attempted the usual, well documented rollback options.  But the recovery options told me I couldn't go back to prior versions of windows (though it also couldn't explain why), and that my only option was a total reinstall.*

*The disk seems fine though.  I was able to mount it (thus far read only) via an external drive case, and I'm not finding any disk errors.  And, at least right now, I still have windows.old there.  I'm hoping that maybe the entire working prior installation is still basically there in Windows.old.  So before I do a total reinstall, I wanted to try manually putting the prior installation back, as kind of a Hail Mary.  I was thinking I'd mount the drive as an external drive on a working PC, or maybe even Linux, and do the equivalent steps that way, rather than attempting to do it on my now nonfunctional laptop.*

Comment: So a rollback if the PC will not boot into Windows?

Comment: See this page...https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12415/windows-10-recovery-options

Comment: Thank you Moab. That's right, I'm looking to do a rollback b/c the PC won't even boot.

I'm aware of the standard Recovery options. I already attempted what's described in the "Recovery options in Windows 10: Go back to the previous version of Windows" section.  It didn't work-- "Sorry, Windows won't be able to bring you back to the previous version" or similar error. And yet I do have Windows.old which looks OK.  Maybe the new install was so damaged, Windows' remains didn't know how to oversee the rollback.

That's why I want to try the manual strategy if it still works in Win10.

Comment: There was a manual way in Windows 7 but not sure if it will work for W10.....https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/971760/how-to-restore-a-windows-7-based-computer-to-a-previous-windows-instal

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? The same happened to me this night...

Comment: I never followed up on this. I did attempt the manual rollback procedure, by moving Windows.old back into place (doing a backup copy first, etc.)  It didn't work in my case.  In the end I went for a total reinstall and copied my personal files and stuff back to the laptop.  It might work for other people, but it didn't work for me.

PS, I should add, the experience did sour me pretty badly on letting Windows update itself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

The same procedure described in MS 971760 does work for Windows 10, too.

Just swap all folders in Windows.old with their twins in root.

Optionally, repair/recreate boot stuff. (needed mostly where there is major version changes)

Reboot and wait... (sometimes for hours...)